# how to call key press using dispatchKeyEvent once per key press in android?

Tags: java, android, keypress

In the below code every time keycode 144 is pressed , i want to perform some function when the time difference between keypress down and up is greater than 1000 millisecond. But i have notice that when keydown exceed around 100 millisecond, it keep on repeatedly calling keydown, instead of waiting for keyup listener and finally calculating difference which is false as it caculate difference from the last keydown time. how to program in such a way that listener should call only once key down until kep up event is trigger

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

```
         long diff=0;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                down = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.e("current_down",String.valueOf((down)));

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.e("current_down2",String.valueOf((down)));

                //this is the time in milliseconds
                diff = (System.currentTimeMillis()- down);
               


                break;
        }

        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        Log.e("javan",String.valueOf((keyCode)));





        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == 144) {


          if(diff >1000){


            //do something 

  }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long diff = 0; // these two values should be declared at the start of the
long down = 0; // method
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(down == 0) {
            down = System.currentTimeMillis(); // save current time if nothing is saved
            Log.e("current_down",String.valueOf((down)));
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        Log.e("current_down2",String.valueOf((down)));

        //this is the time in milliseconds
        diff = (System.currentTimeMillis()- down);
        down = 0; // if you need the value of down afterwards, 
                  // you can create another variable and save it there,
                  // this should be reset to 0 after action up for your case
}
```

Now, there are most certainly other ways, but this one was off the top of my head.